# If statement error (unary Operator Expected)

Tags: bash, shell

I am receiving this error message when comparing two integer values in a bash script `[: 2315669844: unary operator expected`. I have looked up this error and nothing appears to work for my case. Here is part  my script

```
CURR_AVAIL=`df /home2 | tail -1 | awk '{ print $4 }'`   
DIFF_AVAIL=$((CURR_AVAIL-PREV_AVAIL))

echo “---------------------------------------------“ >> sys_log
date >> sys_log
if [ "$DIFF_AVAIL" –gt 1000 ];
        then
        echo $DIFF_AVAIL >> sys_log
elif [ "$DIFF_AVAIL" –lt -1000 ];
        then
        echo $DIFF_AVAIL >> sys_log
fi;
```

Comment: Which line gives the error?

Comment: Run your script in debug mode: `sh -x myscript.sh` to find out where the error is.

Comment: Your `-gt` and `-lt` are not using hyphens, but U+2013. Compare the correct `-gt` to your `–gt`. (Depending on your font, the difference could be subtle or nearly undetectable.)

Comment: Sorry I for got to add that. It is lines 13 and 16 my if statements. `if [ "$DIFF_AVAIL" –gt 1000 ];` and `if [ "$DIFF_AVAIL" –lt 1000 ];`

Comment: The quotes in the first `echo` statement are incorrect as well; they are typographic quotes, not ASCII double quotes. Beware cutting and pasting code with some text editors.

Comment: Here is the output of the sh -x script.sh command.                                      `++ cat PREV_AVAIL
+ PREV_AVAIL=2315669844
++ df /home2
++ tail -1
++ awk '{ print $4 }'
+ CURR_AVAIL=2315669844
+ DIFF_AVAIL=0
+ echo $'\342\200\234---------------------------------------------\342\200\234'
+ date
+ '[' 0 1000 ']'
freeDiskMonitor: line 13: [: 0: unary operator expected
+ '[' 0 -1000 ']'
freeDiskMonitor: line 16: [: 0: unary operator expected`

Comment: Please, update the text of your question, not into a comment!

Comment: Add `set -u -e` in the beginning of the script.

Answer (score 1):

The lines where the error is probably happening are

```
if [ "$DIFF_AVAIL" –gt 1000 ];
```

and

```
elif [ "$DIFF_AVAIL" –lt -1000 ];
```

---

If `$DIFF_AVAIL` is somehow completely empty, then `[ "$DIFF_AVAIL" –lt -1000 ]` will  become   `[  -lt -100]` while `-lt` expect two parameters on its two sides as its a binary operator.

Try `echo`ing `$DIFF_AVAIL` to check if it's empty for some reason. That should the most possible reason here.

---

Also I see some Text-Editor related issue in your code. You have used two different types of `Quote` in you code. One of them (most probably the one that is used in the line with `echo` in it) should be invalid.

Comment: I do not think the variable is empty, here is output of the sh -x myscript.sh command.                                                                                                     `++ cat PREV_AVAIL
+ PREV_AVAIL=2315669844
++ df /home2
++ tail -1
++ awk '{ print $4 }'
+ CURR_AVAIL=2315669844
+ DIFF_AVAIL=0
+ echo $'\342\200\234---------------------------------------------\342\200\234'
+ date
+ '[' 0 1000 ']'
freeDiskMonitor: line 13: [: 0: unary operator expected
+ '[' 0 -1000 ']'
freeDiskMonitor: line 16: [: 0: unary operator expected`

Comment: Edit you code using some clean Text-Editor like `vim` . I think you have just copy-pasted the code into some bad text-editor.

Comment: No recent version of any shell has a problem with `[ "" -lt -1000 ]`; the problem is the operator itself, as I pointed out in the comments. The OP's code uses a Unicode dash, not a hyphen.

Answer (score 1):

Chepner was correct I did not realize that my '-gt and -lt' operators were not using hyphens like I had thought they were. It was reading as if I had typed '--gt and --lt'. I had copied my script from a text editor into vim.

```
CURR_AVAIL=df /home2 | tail -1 | awk '{ print $4 }'  
DIFF_AVAIL=$((CURR_AVAIL-PREV_AVAIL))

echo “---------------------------------------------“ >> sys_log
date >> sys_log
if [ "$DIFF_AVAIL" -gt 1000 ];
        then
        echo $DIFF_AVAIL >> sys_log
elif [ "$DIFF_AVAIL" -lt -1000 ];
        then
        echo $DIFF_AVAIL >> sys_log
fi;
```

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Very sneaky. If you install [syntastic](https://github.com/vim-syntastic/syntastic) and [shellcheck](http://shellcheck.net), Vim will immediately complain and say "This is a unicode dash. Delete and retype as ASCII minus.".